# i want to show mysql data using backgroudworker and dtagridview

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datagridview, backgroundworker

I have problem when i'm trying to fetch data from mysql database

I always get the last record.

How can I get all records showing on the datagridview synchronously

Here is my code

Please can someone help me

```
Public Class Form1

    Private RowCount As Integer = 0


    Private Sub bgw_ProgressChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged
        ListBox1.Items.Add(e.UserState)
        ProgressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage
        Label1.Text = "Processing row.. " + e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() 
        DataGridView1.Rows.Add(New Object() {f1, f2})
         Me.ProgressBar1.Maximum = RowCount 

    End Sub
    Dim ListText As String
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles go.Click
        go.Enabled = False
        cancel.Enabled = True
        ListBox1.Items.Clear()
        ProgressBar1.Value = 0
        BackgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = True
        BackgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True
        BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
        Me.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cancel.Click
        BackgroundWorker1.CancelAsync()
    End Sub

    Private Sub bgw_RunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted
        go.Enabled = True
        cancel.Enabled = False
        Me.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow

        DataGridView1.Refresh()
        DataGridView1.CurrentCell = DataGridView1(0, DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1)
    End Sub
    Dim f1 As String
    Dim f2 As String
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim command As MySqlCommand
    Dim reader As MySqlDataReader
    Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
         GetRecordCount()
        Dim connetionString As String
        Dim connection As MySqlConnection
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        Dim sql As String
        connetionString = "Server=db4free.net;User Id=mouhcindinaoui;Password=$$$$$$;Database=mouhcindinaoui"

        sql = "SELECT id,nom FROM dep02 "
        connection = New MySqlConnection(connetionString)
        Try

            connection.Open()
            command = New MySqlCommand(sql, connection)
            reader = command.ExecuteReader()
            For Value As Integer = 0 To rowcount

                If reader.HasRows Then
                    Do While reader.Read()

                        f1 = reader.GetString("id")
                        f2 = reader.GetString("nom")

                    Loop
                End If
                ListText = String.Concat("Sequence #", Value)
                BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(Value, ListText)
                Thread.Sleep(10)

            Next
            reader.Close()
            command.Dispose()
            connection.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            '   MsgBox("Can not open connection ! ")
        End Try
    End Sub
    Private Sub GetRecordCount()
        Dim connetionString As String
        Dim connection As MySqlConnection
        Dim command As MySqlCommand
        Dim sql As String
        connetionString = "Server=db4free.net;User Id=mouhcindinaoui;Password=dinaouimouhcin1991;Database=mouhcindinaoui"

        sql = "Select count(*) from dep02"
        connection = New MySqlConnection(connetionString)
        command = New MySqlCommand(sql, connection)
        connection.Open()
        RowCount = CInt(command.ExecuteScalar())

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: You really dont need all that: you could fill a datatable and bind it to the DGV very easily.  you can pass other data from ReportProgress, but that is not what it is for

Answer (score 1):

You are calling ReportProgress only at the end of the loop on the DataReader. Of course, at that point the two variables f1 and f2 used to set items in your grid contain the value of the last record read by the DataReader.

You need to move the call inside the DataReader loop

```
    For Value As Integer = 0 To rowcount

        If reader.HasRows Then
            Do While reader.Read()

                f1 = reader.GetString("id")
                f2 = reader.GetString("nom")
                ListText = String.Concat("Sequence #", Value)
                BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(Value, ListText)
            Loop
        End If
        Thread.Sleep(10)
    Next
```

However it is totally useless the call to GetRecordCount and the external loop on the rowcount variable (*and plain wrong*). The while loop on the DataReader doesn't need it and your could remove all of it replacing everything with a simple increment of a local variable to keep the progressive of the current record inside the datareader loop

```
Dim recNum = 1
If reader.HasRows Then
    Do While reader.Read()

        f1 = reader.GetString("id")
        f2 = reader.GetString("nom")

        ListText = String.Concat("Sequence #", recNum)
        BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(Value, ListText)
        recNum = recNum + 1
    Loop
End If
```